# Oracle PL/SQL: get tag values while looping

Tags: plsql, xml-parsing

### I have an xml with the following type of content

```
<DATA>
  <CUSTOMER>
    <BASIC_INFO>
         <F_NAME>TOM<F_NAME>
         <M_NAME>AND<M_NAME>
         <L_NAME>HANKS<L_NAME>
    </BASIC_INFO>
    <ADDITIONAL_INFO>
         <EMAIL>TOM.HANKS@GMAIL.COM</EMAIL>
         <PHONE_NO>22211132</PHONE_NO>
    </ADDITIONAL_INFO>
  </CUSTOMER>

  <CUSTOMER>
    <BASIC_INFO>
         <F_NAME>TOM<F_NAME>
         <L_NAME>HANKS<L_NAME>
    </BASIC_INFO>
    <ADDITIONAL_INFO>
         <EMAIL>TOM.HANKS@GMAIL.COM</EMAIL>
    </ADDITIONAL_INFO>
  </CUSTOMER>

  <CUSTOMER>
    <BASIC_INFO>
         <F_NAME>TOM<F_NAME>
    </BASIC_INFO>
    <ADDITIONAL_INFO>
        <PHONE_NO>22211132</PHONE_NO>
    </ADDITIONAL_INFO>
  </CUSTOMER>
```

I want to store the information of a customer in the table with columns as F_NAME,M_NAME,L_NAME,PHONE_NO,EMAIL and each value should go in the respective column

Now the point to be noted is that for the customers for which some information is not there for them the value in the table should not be inserted.

Comment: somebody please ans this question......m dying without the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps.

First create a relational representation of you data:

Example from [sql-plsql-de.blogspot.co.at](http://sql-plsql-de.blogspot.co.at/2007/10/xml-dokumente-relational-aufbereiten.html):

```
create table xmltest (
  dokument xmltype
)
/

insert into xmltest values (xmltype(
'<blog>
  <name>SQL und PL/SQL</name>
  <autor>Carsten Czarski</autor>
  <themen>
    <thema>XML</thema>
    <thema>PL/SQL</thema>
  </themen>
</blog>'
))
/
```

This Statement:

```
select
  extractvalue(dokument, '/blog/name') as blog_name,
  extractvalue(dokument, '/blog/autor') as blog_autor,
  extractvalue(value(thema), '/thema/text()') as thema
from xmltest,
  table(xmlsequence(extract(dokument, '/blog/themen/thema'))) thema
/
```

Re sluts in:

```
BLOG_NAME            BLOG_AUTOR      THEMA
-------------------- --------------- --------------------
SQL und PL/SQL       Carsten Czarski XML
SQL und PL/SQL       Carsten Czarski PL/SQL
```

Now that you have it in a relational way you can loop over it:

```
for cur in (select * from ...) 
loop
  if cur.column_a is not null then
    --insert
  end if;
end loop;
```

This is slow but stays readable even if you have complex rules.
Alternatively you can use 'normal' SQL or maybe merge statement.